# ClassCastException when inflating a FrameLayout in a GridView

Tags: android

I'm trying to inflate a FrameLayout in a GridView and I'm getting an exception. Here is the getView method from the adapter (a subclass of BaseAdapter):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO: Create compound view with image and name overlayed on top
    FrameLayout personFrame;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        personFrame = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.thumbnail, null);
        //personFrame = (FrameLayout)View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.thumbnail, null);
        personFrame.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
    } else {
        personFrame = (FrameLayout) convertView;
    }
```

.... and so on

Here's the layout I'm inflating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="85px"
android:layout_height="85px">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail_image"
    android:layout_height="85px"
    android:padding="2px"
    android:layout_width="85px"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/person_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

    android:padding="2dip"

    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"

    android:text="Me" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I've tried with and without setting the LayoutParams explicitly and I get the same exception each time, which is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  420): java.lang.ClassCastException:        android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:934)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  420):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong here? 
Many thanks

Answer (score -5, accepted):

GridView is not a FrameLayout, both are ViewGroups but it's not a FrameLayout.

Comment: If I change GridView.LayoutParams to FrameLayout.LayoutParams I get the same stacktrace, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: that you get a ClassCastException, like trying to cast a Banana to an Apple. You can cast Banana to fruit, but not to an Apple. Read in the Android javadoc what is the inheritance of these 2 classes, and read in the web for "Java inheritance" to gain a general knowledge of this topic.

Comment: I understand what a class cast exception is, I'm asking what's causing it - the stacktrace is entirely SDK code so it's pretty obscure as to how I managed to break it. I searched and searched and I can't find any explanation of how I should do this (use FrameLayouts inflated in a GridView).

Answer (score 18):

Actually returning the wrong object from getView (as you mentioned you were doing) is what caused the Exception. For example if you returned a button from within your FrameLayout instead of the FrameLayout itself this will cause the problem you describe. The GridView code is taking the View object you return and walking one step up the View hierarchy. There it expects to find an AbsListView (which it wraps each grid view item in). Because you returned a sub-element of your FrameLayout, the GridView class found a FrameLayout where it expected an AbsListView.

Comment: Yes, this was also the right answer for me, the "accepted" answer isn't even an answer at all, it helps nobody actually solve this problem

Answer (score 9):

Try changing:

```
personFrame.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
```

to:

```
personFrame.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(85,85));
```

It seems that when you set `LayoutParams` of an object, it should be cast-able to the parent's `LayoutParams`. In your case, the parent of `personFrame` is the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what was going on, but removing the setLayoutParams fixed it. I don't know how to set those parameters in code, but it doesn't appear to be necessary so that's fine. I also made the stupid mistake of returning the wrong object from the getView method, but that wasn't affecting this crash.